# SSRS Report Rendering

Tags: reporting-services, rendering, ssrs-2012, renderer

Not sure if this is even possible to fix or not but I have made a report and in the body of said report is have a large .jpeg image inside a single cell of a tablix. There is only one cell in the entire tablix and have done that to allow me to  group and sort the data that is displayed.

The issue is that over the jpeg image I have several fields that are overlapping with the image, there is no other way I can do this that I can think of due to the complexity of the image and the image is a diagram of a part of the plant and how it is physically set up on site.

When I go to preview the report the jpeg shows at the top of the report but all of the data that is overlapped on top of the image is shifted down to the bottom on the report (Just below the image). When exported out to a PDF the report looks fine with all of the data in the correct place as it does not seem to care that data is overlapped over a image.

The reports are downloaded from a web based server which also allows the user to preview the report within the browser it self. The big issue is that the rendering of the report in the web browser is the same as the rendering the preview window with all of the data shifted below the diagram image.

Is it possible to change the default render to be same as what is used in the PDF format or is this something we will just have to live with? Sorry for the long winded question as I cant really post any screenshots.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is maybe your report size isn't set to the same size as the PDF output? Assuming that you're rendering the PDF as A4 landscape, then the report also needs to match, at the least, the interactive size of the report.

Comment: I have got it set up as A3 Landscape in Visual Studio and the same in the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force the report to render a certain way. It's usually better to just stick with one format and make sure your users know to look at it in PDF, for example. Otherwise, you can use a hack to make it look better.

If you want to prevent the text from overlapping the image, a hack we used was to put an invisible line across the table cell. Since the cell now has something in it, the other cells don't overlap. Not sure if it'll work in this case, though.

Comment: Ok thanks, not ideal and unfortunately this hack wont really work in our circumstance but thanks for the clarification!

Comment: have you looked into using a background image? or a background image in a rectangle? there's usually a hack you can use, but it often takes hours to figure out...

Comment: No I have never even heard of a background image will have a look into it. Thanks